# bash script to grab screen output and parse to csv

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am writing a bash script to grab the screen output  when I run a custom script called chk and output this to csv.

Sample of screen output from chk command

```
type:   ISDSL ACCESS ADSL
circt:  219317638
speed:  4096
rroutr: Billion 7404 (IS)
intr:   196.214.12.124/30
vrf:     PCTPT
```

My command $line could be any linetag

```
chk $line | egrep 'type|circt|speed|rroutr|intr|vrf' | awk'{if(NR==1){print "  Circuit,Speed,CE,,WAN IP,VRF";}
else{print $2 $3} ORS=","}'
```

The output for this is

```
Circuit,Speed,CE,,WAN IP,VRF
219317638,4096,Billion,196.214.12.124/30,PCTPT
```

Following this I want input to the script a list of items ($line) I want to run the custom script on and parse each screen output into the csv file.

```
# This script takes in a file of many $line's and runs the chk command on each line usage  ./parsechk2csv <filename>
#!/bin/bash
cat $1|while read line; do
echo "$line\n";
chk $line | egrep 'type|circt|speed|rroutr|intr|vrf' | awk'{if(NR==1) {print "";}else{print $2 $3} ORS=","}' >> test.csv
done
```

its working more or less but there are 2 things I am having difficulty with.

1. How do I include the csv file headings in my final script without the loop in the shell script rewriting the headings all the time (you will notice that I left the headings out of my current script awk command). Using NR==1 also overwrites the first line in my screen output which I need
2. How can I use the command args to specify the name of the output csv file. I tried to redirect to >>$3.csv but this doesnt work.

Comment: The entries in your data line are less than your header line... That appears wrong. Even if one of the column is missing, you must insert a placeholder column. something like `219317638,4096,,pep-ctn3-dsl/e0,Billion,196.214.12.124/30,` Notice 2 `,` after `4096`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback anishane. I forgot to mention I would like to add the $line variable to be the data for the first field in the csv file

Comment: Regardless of your comment, you still have **7** fields in your header line `LineTag,Circuit,Type,PE,Speed,WAN IP,VRF`, and **only 5** fields in the awk output: `219317638,4096,pep-ctn3-dsl/e0,Billion,196.214.12.124/30,`. (Or 6 when we take the last comma as an field separator for the 6th (empty) field), and only **6** lines in your input. The question is inconsistent. For example the `speed` is in the 5th column in the header and the 2nd column (4096) in the data line. So, edit the question, correct it, and add the example output(s) what do you really want.

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear which lines of your input file map to which fields in your output as the values you show don't seem to make sense wrt the names in the header line but this is how to do what you want:

```
$ cat file
first linetag
type:   ISDSL ACCESS ADSL
circt:  219317638
speed:  4096
routr:  ctn3-dsl/e0
rroutr: Billion 7404 (IS)
intr:   196.214.12.124/30
vrf:    first idk

second linetag
type:   Next fake ACCESS
circt:  123456
speed:  2020
routr:  foo-hspd/e1
rroutr: dozens 6564 (IS)
intr:   100.200.30.304/27
vrf:    second idk
```

.

```
$ cat tst.sh
#infile="$1"
#outfile="${2:-test.csv}"
#<"$infile" xargs -d'\n' -n1 -Iline sh -c 'echo "line"; chk "line"' |
cat file |
awk -v RS= -F'\n' -v OFS="," '
BEGIN {
    split("LineTag,Router,Type,Circuit,Speed,PE,WANIP,VRF",names,/,/)
    split("linetag,routr,type,circt,speed,rroutr,intr,vrf",abbrs,/,/)
}
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i in names; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", (i>1?OFS:""), names[i]
    }
    print ""
}
{
    delete abbr2value
    abbr2value[abbrs[1]] = $1
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        abbr = value = $i
        sub(/:.*/,"",abbr)
        sub(/[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,"",value)
        abbr2value[abbr] = value
    }
    for (i=1; i in abbrs; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", (i>1?OFS:""), abbr2value[abbrs[i]]
    }
    print ""
}'
#}' >> "$outfile"
```

.

```
$ ./tst.sh
LineTag,Router,Type,Circuit,Speed,PE,WANIP,VRF
first linetag,ctn3-dsl/e0,ISDSL ACCESS ADSL,219317638,4096,Billion 7404 (IS),196.214.12.124/30,first idk
second linetag,foo-hspd/e1,Next fake ACCESS,123456,2020,dozens 6564 (IS),100.200.30.304/27,second idk
```

Just replace the `cat file` (which is just being used to emulate the output of running `chk` twice for the purposes of demonstrating the awk script working) with the currently commented out lines at the start of the script, and replace the `}'` at the end with the currently commented out `}' >> "$outfile"` and change the order of the fields in the `split()` commands as you see fit.

Note that the significant differences above from what you have today are that:

1. You no longer have an explicit shell loop, instead you use xargs to iterate through the input file contents (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for why that matters), and
2. You now run awk once on the output of all invocations of chk rather than running awk once for each separate invocation of chk.

Comment: thanks Ed. Greatly appreciated. Apologies for the confusing headings. If I wanted to add $line as the first item in the csv and then the other fields from the screen output . Basically $line would be the value for linetag and I will add another header field to match what I am grabbing from the screen output

Comment: OK, I updated my answer but it really would help if you just edit your question to show concise, testable sample input and exactly the output you want given that input.

Comment: Thank you Ed. I will most definitely improve the input i present going forward. I have tried the new script but I seem to only get one line in my output csv file. In the previous script it generated the csv for all the lines in an input file. I will investigate further t see what might be causing it

Comment: The awk script WILL work so you just need to investigate `xargs...chk`. Try `<"$infile" xargs -d'\n' -n1 -Iline sh -c 'echo "line"; chk "line"' | awk '{print NR, NF, "<" $0 ">"}'` to see if the `xargs...chk` is producing the output you think it should.